# Rendering a view to a string in ASP.NET MVC 2

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, viewrendering

We need to render an `ActionResult` to a `string` to add pages to our internal search engine index. We settled on [this solution to render to string](http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2008/06/mvc-framework-capturing-output-of-view_05.html).

I've run into a problem with the `ExecuteResult` call used to process the View.

#### Code Snippet:

```
var oldController = controllerContext.RouteData.Values["controller"];
controllerContext.RouteData.Values["controller"] = 
                  typeof(TController).Name.Replace("Controller", "");

viewResult.ExecuteResult(controllerContext); // this line breaks
```

I receive the following error:

> `"Object reference not set to instance of object" error.`

I've confirmed `viewResult` is not null, so the exception has to be thrown internally in `ExecuteResult`.

What could we be missing?

Comment: Spark provides rendering view to string out of the box and friction less. :)

Comment: Yeah, but porting all of our views to Spark isn't really practical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. The issue with ExecuteResult wasn't working as expected was because I hadn't mocked the ControllerContext properly. I was able to solve the issue by mocking the controllercontext as described in this SO post:

[Mocking Asp.net-mvc Controller Context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32640/mocking-asp-net-mvc-controller-context)

Hope this post helps someone in the future if they're trying to do something similar.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it myself but [Phil Haack](http://haacked.com) did suggest a way to [output a view to a string](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/05/29/writing-page-to-string.aspx) here with MVC in mind.

Answer (score 0):

[MVCContrib has a BlockRenderer class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/980947/convert-c-to-vb-net-using-mvccontrib-blockrenderer-to-render-a-partial-view-to) which could be helpful for this scenario.

Comment: Yeah, but it seems the BlockRenderer class has been deprecated in the latest version of MVCContrib that's compatible with MVC2 RC2.

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer to your question, but why would you render the whole view as a string to your search index, rather than either a) pushing the data itself into the index (LINQ to Lucene lets you do this w/ attributes) or b) offloading the work to a separate process that crawls the front end using some set of rights?