# How to Retrieve Html code from current Page in Post Method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

i need some help with an asp.net MVC 4 Application, i want to retrieve html from current page in HttpPost Method, can anyone help me?

Comment: What do you mean by `retrieve html`?

Comment: Better if you include some more details.

Comment: i want to get html from current page when it's doing Post in controller

Comment: what html you want, and why!

Comment: html from my current page in web application and save it as PDF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recomend to render the view by yourself and save the result as PDF ([Render View programmatically into a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3234003/render-view-programmatically-into-a-string)). But if you need the client HTML you have to pass it to the controller via user-input. Try this:

1) Make an hidden field

```
@Html.Hidden("ClientHTML")
```

2) Update the field before you submit the form:

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    $('#myform').submit(function(){
        var pageHTML = '<html>' + $('html').html() + '</html>';
        $('#ClientHTML').val(pageHTML);
    });
});
```

You will then have to allow HTML content in your POST, as described [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621272/allow-user-to-input-html-in-asp-net-mvc).